# Merge two lists by adding data from list 2 where there is a matching criteria, to list 1

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to merge two lists of data such that the combined list has

- all data from list 1
- data from list 2 where there is a matching criteria

I have an Excel table on a sheet of projects with various info i.e. name, Project ID, start date, end date, etc.

```
ProjName |  ID   | Sart Dt  |  End Dt   | ...   
project1 | 12345 | 2/1/2020 | 3/30/2020 | ...
```

I have a second Excel table with the common Project ID, resource name, and then a series of dates (week starting) and the number of days that someone is assigned to a project.

```
ProjName | Resource | 1-20 | 1-27 | 2-3 | 2-10 | 2-17 | 2-24
project1 | Bill     | 5    |   5  |  2  |   2  |  5   |  
project1 | Alex     |      |      |  3  |   3  |      |  5
```

I want a combined list of each project from the first sheet with a complete set of data from the first sheet whether or not the data exists in the second Excel table.  For each resource on a project in sheet two I want a new line with all the data.

```
project1 | 12345 | 2/1/2020 | 3/30/2020 | Bill | .......
project1 | 12345 | 2/1/2020 | 3/30/2020 | Alex | .......
```

Is there a way to do this or would it require VBA code to create the list?

Also is there is a way to pull in projects that occur >= Today and only bring over the grid of dates that are >= Today?

Comment: Take a look into Power Query

Comment: Indeed, I would use VBA.

Comment: Sounds like you'd like to write a left join on these tables. And then you want a WHERE clause to filter to projects that occur in the future. What if I told you that you can write some SQL and execute it with VBA :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with Power Query in the end.  Merge Data.

Comment: Please add details

Comment: I can't provide too much insight here as it was some time ago and in the end wasn't used :-(  BUT, what I did do was used Power Query from "Get & Transform Data" and then used the Merge Queries to combine the data results of each table of data.  I really did work very nicely and functioned perfectly but we ended up with another approach altogether.  -Rob